# Using COLLATE inside Doctrine DQL Query (Symfony2)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I can't find anything related to using COLLATE in a DQL query with Doctrine (and ofcourse it doesn't seem to work).

My specific problem:

I have a table with `utf8_general_ci` charset. I have one specific field in it which has accented characters (like 'á', 'ű', 'ő' etc.)

A basic comparison with `utf8_general_ci` is not able to determine the difference between regular chars and their accented pairs (a = á, u = ű, o = ő), which is perfectly fine for me for the majority of the queries that land on that table! So if I have let's say:

```
 col1 |  col2
------|-------
   1  | árvíz  
------|-------
   2  | arviz
```

This query will return both results:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `col2` = 'arviz'
```

Again, this is perfectly fine for me for most of the use cases!

But there is one specific funcionality, where I need to determine the difference, and in regular MySQL I could use:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `col2` COLLATE utf8_bin = 'arviz'
```

This returns only the unaccented version.

The question is, can something like this be done using either Doctrine's createQuery (write the dql), or query builder?

I think I've read throught all the relevant documentation, but cannot find a way to do this. Is is possible somehow?

Comment: Worse case is you can make yourself a custom DQL function: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html.  But I kind of think that you can avoid this when creating the table.

Comment: I need the table structure to remain like this, becouse I use the benefits of `ci`. I try to find a custom COLLATE dql.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Following Cerad 's suggestion to write a custom DQL function:
http://www.doctrine-project.org/2010/03/29/doctrine2-custom-dql-udfs.html

I managed to create this:

```
namespace MyCompany\MyBundle\DQL;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;

class CollateFunction extends FunctionNode
{
    public $expressionToCollate = null;
    public $collation = null;

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->expressionToCollate = $parser->StringPrimary();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $lexer = $parser->getLexer();
        $this->collation = $lexer->token['value'];

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return sprintf( '%s COLLATE %s', $this->expressionToCollate->dispatch($sqlWalker), $this->collation );
    }
}
```

When registered to the config.yml (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html)
This will look for a Collate 'function' with two arguments: a field and a charset (no valid charset detection yet).

Works like (written in DQL)

```
COLLATE( field , collation )
```

And creates (in runable MySQL)

```
`field` COLLATE collation
```

Ofcourse collation should be a valid charset (such as `utf8_bin`) or you will get a MySQL error.

I guess there is a simpler solution, but I only could create this as a 'function'. At least the problem is solved.

Comment: Looks like someone turned your answer into a library 
https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/src/Query/Mysql/Collate.php

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting an error: `Cannot use object of type Doctrine\Common\Lexer\Token as array` after upgrading to `Symfony v6.4`

then you need to adjust one line in your `CollateFunction`

> FROM: `$this->collation = $lexer->token['value'];`

> TO: `$this->collation = $lexer->token->value;`