# Query using accent mark Doctrine + Symfony + PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine

I have a method in Doctrine repository to search a person like this:

```
 function search($value)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
    $qb->where($qb->expr()->like(
        'LOWER(p.lastName)',
        "'%" . mb_strtolower($value) . "%'"));
}
```

Example:

| No | Name | Last name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Luis | Sanchez |
| 2 | David | Sánchez |

When I use this method and the input is 'Sanchez' only returns record No. 1, and if the input is 'Sánchez' only returns record No. 2 (Change a for á). I need to get all records from my database no matter if the input contains any accent mark (á, é, í, ó, ú).

Comment: I'm gonna say collation, and leave it at that. Learn what it is, adapt your database/table/column.

Comment: Don't use `LOWER()`. The proper (and also easier) solution is to set a [collation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/collation.html) (a set of rules to determine how to compare text in, I presume, Spanish).

Comment: Thanks, you put me in the right direction, I search for Doctrine integration with collation and find some interesting post like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325898/using-collate-inside-doctrine-dql-query-symfony2, I recommend this type of solution.

Answer (score 0):

That function could be solution for your problem [unaccent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/unaccent.html).

And example code here:

```
CREATE TABLE p (
    last_name varchar(40) NOT NULL    
);

INSERT INTO p VALUES ('Sanchez');
INSERT INTO p VALUES ('Sánchez');

SELECT p.last_name FROM p WHERE unaccent(p.last_name) LIKE CONCAT('%', unaccent('Sánchez'), '%');
SELECT p.last_name FROM p WHERE unaccent(p.last_name) LIKE CONCAT('%', unaccent('Sanchez'), '%');
```

And the results:

| last_name |
| --- |
| Sanchez |
| Sánchez |

| last_name |
| --- |
| Sanchez |
| Sánchez |

Comment: you're proposing double calls over collations?

Comment: @jakumi have you read how that function exactly works? It's depend on rules dictionaries not collations. I belive that is not very fast option to resolve that problem but seems to works.

Comment: I have. And in this case, I would still prefer [collations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/collation.html) since it doesn't require applying unaccent to every datum over and over again (essentially once for every row for every query modulo caching). that's why I ask why you would prefer unaccent over collations, purely out of curiosity.

Comment: Becouse of currently only I proposed solution that resolves the problem, not only suggestion :)